# Getting 401 Unauthorized when I believe it should be a solid 200 Rspec 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to do the following RSpec test:

```
it "should publish the request information" do
  post :create, {
    :response_code => 200,
    :response_base_url => 'http://google.ca',
    :response_headers => {:some_site => 'some_site'},
    :publish_to_site => {:site_name => 'sample'}
  }, {
    "Authorization" => "Token token=\"#{YAML.load(File.read('config/application.yml'))['TEST_APP_API_KEY'].to_s}\"",
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
  }

  expect(response.status).to eql 200
end
```

I believe this should pass because the API key actually exists in the system, but instead the response code coming back is a 401

It dies, when trying to post in this method:

```
    def restrict_application_api_access
      authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
        @api_key = ApplicationApiKey.find_by(api_key: token)
      end
    end
```

The specific place it dies is:

```
      # Right here ...
      authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
        @api_key = ApplicationApiKey.find_by(api_key: token)
      end
```

It never gets into the block.

So before that I did a `binding.pry` to investigate the request information coming in. The interesting part is:

```
"rack.session"=>
    {"Authorization"=>"Token token=\"################################\"", "Content-Type"=>"application/json"},
```

The authorization token is being passed through and the content type is set, and the parameters are even set too:

```
"action_dispatch.request.request_parameters"=>
    {"response_code"=>"200",
     "response_base_url"=>"http://google.ca",
     "response_headers"=>{"some_site"=>"some_site"},
     "publish_to_site"=>{"site_name"=>"sample"}},
   "action_dispatch.request.path_parameters"=>{"controller"=>"api/internal/v1/response_analytics", "action"=>"create"},
   "action_dispatch.request.flash_hash"=>#<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x007ff84a08c380 @discard=#<Set: {}>, @flashes={}, @now=nil>,
   "PATH_INFO"=>"/internal/v1/response_analytics",
```

I can make this request from a third party app and get a 200 from posting the information, when I try and do it from the app its self in a test it fails and gives me a 401. Am I setting the headers wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your output shows you are setting the authorization and content type in the session rather than as headers.

To set headers in a spec you just do

```
request.headers["Authorization"] = "..."
request.headers["Content-Type"] = "..."
```

Before you send the request.